# How to skip further execution in Nunit test case once particular assert passes

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, nunit-2.5, nunit-console, nunit-2.5.9

Below is my test case,

```
Public static void SampleTest() 
{
    // Pre conditions for both assert 1 and 2
    if(condition1)
    {
        // Assert 1
    }
    // Pre condition for Assert 2
    // Assert 2
}
```

Once condition1 satisfied and assert 1 executes I don't want to execute the further statements in above test case. On the other hand, if condition1 fails it should execute precondition for assert 2 and should publish the result based on assert 2

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call `return;` after `Assert 1`:

```
Public static void SampleTest() 
{
    // Pre conditions for both assert 1 and 2
    if(condition1)
    {
        // Assert 1
        return;
    }
    // Pre condition for Assert 2
    // Assert 2
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Am searching for a option from NUNIT framework. Please consider the above use case has some post condition which is to be executed for both assert. Retun statement won't help me in such case.